# Button onClick prevent focus on another form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus

I have form with few input field, one of the input fields has button where users can click. After the click on that button automatically focus will jump to the top form field. I would like to prevent focus on any field because onClick will show modal box in this case. Here is example:

```
<form name="frmSaveuser" id="frmSaveuser" class="frm-agencySubmit" data-frm="SaveUser" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-primary">Active Staff:<span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" id="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" required>
             <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
             <option value="0">No</option>
             <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="position"><span class="label label-primary">Position:</span></label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_position" id="frmSaveaccount_position" placeholder="Choose Position" readonly>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success modal-master" name="btn-position" id="btn-position" data-code="position">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Here is JQuery code:

```
$('.modal-master').on('click',showMaster);
function showMaster() {
    var masterCode = $(this).data('code');
    console.log(masterCode);
}
```

If anyone know the way how to prevent focus in my function please let me know.

Comment: can you provide a working snippet ?

Comment: pass event to your function then use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @BooBerr'ita That fixed the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @espresso_coffee you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

It focus on top field because default behaviour of button element is to submit form.

If you don't want to submit form on button click, you have to add `type="button"` to your html of button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success modal-master" name="btn-position" id="btn-position" data-code="position">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the event prevent default :

first pass the event to your function then use the [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault); to prevent event default action .

```js
$('.modal-master').on('click',showMaster);
function showMaster(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var masterCode = $(this).data('code');
    console.log(masterCode);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmSaveuser" id="frmSaveuser" class="frm-agencySubmit" data-frm="SaveUser" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="activestaff"><span class="label label-primary">Active Staff:</span> </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" id="frmSaveaccount_activestaff" required>
             <option value="">-- Select the option --</option>
             <option value="0">No</option>
             <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="control-label" for="position"><span class="label label-primary">Position:</span></label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frmSaveaccount_position" id="frmSaveaccount_position" placeholder="Choose Position" readonly>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success modal-master" name="btn-position" id="btn-position" data-code="position">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```